# Powershell script to get and send all Jenkins job's details for last 15 days as attachment

Tags: powershell, user, jenkins, report

I am new on Jenkins and I wants powershell script to get the details of all jobs of Jenkins for last 15 days. I will send that details of Jenkin's jobs over mail to my Manager.

I have tried below script and I would be very thankful if any one resolve my Query.

```
Hour=24;
Minute=60;
Second=60;
oneDayInSecond=hour*minute*second;
sevenDayInSecond=hour*minute*second*7;
now=Calendar.instance;
List=[];
Println("${now.time}");

checkNewProjects(Hudson.instance.items)

def checkNewProjects(items) {
    For (items in items) {
        last_build = items.lastbuild //or item.getlastbuild()
        If (last_build) {
            build_time = last_build.timestamp
            If (now.time.time/1000-build_time.time.time/1000<sevenDayInSecond) {
                item.save()
                Println(item.name)
                Println("\t\tlast build was built in less than 7 days");
                Println("\t\tlast built was at ${build_time.time);
                list<< item;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on below url I have created the script that I posted in this question **stackoverflow.com/q/34797048/17772953**.

Comment: I also installed global build stats plugin. From here also I am getting the details of all Jenkins job but still having the same problem that how can send the output of global build stats as attachment over mail to my Manager.

Comment: I need help in one step that how can I send the output of global build stats data output as attachment over mail to my manager. Please help me in resolving this query

Comment: Can anyone please resolve this query.

Comment: Can anyone please resolve this query?

Comment: Can anyone please resolve this query